# Have problem in emulator as it is taking long time to launch activity

Tags: android

whenever I try to launch the activity the emulator will not come first time.Rather it will come second time after pressing again run. And sometimes even though emulator launches it would not render the contents in layout file.
Please let me know whats the problem and I want emulator to be launched quite
fast

Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)(with warning)

Comment: do you have a complicated layout? or do you get the same problem with a hello world app?

Comment: Its not that much complcate but the layout with cardview

Answer (score 1):

I know (0xC0000005) can sometimes be caused due to too many objects being present. So perhaps see if you can save a backup, and edit down what you have. Unless of course, it is a smaller project.